# orientation error causing crash

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation

I have an activity that sets orientation to lanscape for the activity which works fine, but if the phone is in portrait mode when the activity is launched i get this error and the activity stops and goes back to the other activity:

```
05-30 11:06:48.335: D/DOMX(125): ERROR: failed check:(eError == OMX_ErrorNone) || (eError == OMX_ErrorNoMore) - returning error: 0x80001005 - Error returned from OMX API in ducati
05-30 11:06:48.335: E/CameraHAL(125): Error while configuring rotation 0x80001005
05-30 11:06:48.460: D/DOMX(125): ERROR: failed check:(eError == OMX_ErrorNone) || (eError == OMX_ErrorNoMore) - returning error: 0x80001005 - Error returned from OMX API in ducati
05-30 11:06:48.460: E/CameraHAL(125): Error while configuring rotation 0x80001005
05-30 11:06:48.765: E/CameraHAL(125): Adapter state switch PREVIEW_ACTIVE Invalid Op! event = 0xf
```

The activity is being called from another activity that is also set to landscape and it doesn't crash if i switch activities while holding the device in landscape.. only when holding the device in portrait from at time of launch..

in both activities i set the orientation in the onCreate() like so:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

It seems to have to do with the fact that i am placing a CameraPreview surface in the activity that is launching so i am including the camera class incase that is the problem:

```
public class KNCamLayer extends SurfaceView {
        Camera camera;
        SurfaceHolder previewHolder;

        public KNCamLayer(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            previewHolder = this.getHolder();

            //previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceHolderListener);

        }

        SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceHolderListener = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                camera=Camera.open();
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);

            }
                catch (Throwable e){ }
            }
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
            {
                Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                //params.setPreviewSize(width, height);
                params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.startPreview();


            }
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0)
            {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
            }

        };

        public void onResume() {
            camera.startPreview();

        }

        public void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            camera.stopPreview();
        }

}
```

The CameraView is added in the activity's onResume() like so:

```
camPreview = new KNCamLayer(this);
        frame.addView(camPreview, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems that if i set the orientation in the manifest for that activity.. the problem goes away.. but i am not understanding exactly why.
 fix:

`android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in manifest for activity

Comment: it'e because this property forces your camera activity to be in landscape, that doesn't give option device itself to decide which view it wants to perform when Orientation is not defined